# npm install on modules not in node_modules/

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm building a project and I want to split it up into different modules. I know I should put modules into `node_modules/` but I want to commit the modules to the main version control for the time being (I'm using `.gitignore` to ignore the `node_modules/` directory at the moment).

My current project setup:

```
services/
services/service1/package.json
services/service1/index.js
services/service2/package.json
services/service2/index.js
node_modules/*
app.js
package.json
```

My problem is it works with relative `require`s but the dependences in the `services/*/package.json` aren't loaded. Only the main `package.json` are loaded.

Is this a good approach? Is there a better one? What command can I run to install all the dependences? This is more of a problem for my CI/CD setup.

Thanks.

Comment: Some modules are platform specific, I don't think putting them under version control is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

i found similar feature request here https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/4017 and seems you can't do it

one approach i see is to create soft links from node_modules to services you want and maintain them somehow

maybe you can use https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-scripts.html `postinstall` script for this?

Comment: I was thinking a custom script in `postinstall` would be a good start but I totally failed to write the script. I found `find . -name package.json -maxdepth 2 -execdir npm install \;` but couldn't get it to work as desired.

Comment: i'm not good at bash programming, personally i will prefer node/js script for this (since you have npm, you can run js scripts from console, why not)